# Using transactions with peewee without using `atomic()`

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, peewee

We have a file `db.py` where a peewee database is defined:

```
db = PostgresqlExtDatabase('mom',
                           user=DB_CONFIG['username'],
                           password=DB_CONFIG['password'],
                           host=DB_CONFIG['host'],
                           port=DB_CONFIG['port'],
                           threadlocals=True,
                           register_hstore=False,
                           autocommit=True,
                           autorollback=True,
                           cursor_factory=DictCursor)
```

Calling `db.execute("SOME RAW SQL UPDATE QUERY")` works as expected.
But calling a `begin` before that does not stop the DB from being modified.

```
db.begin()
db.execute("SOME RAW SQL UPDATE QUERY")  # <- Does not wait, db is updated immediately here
db.commit()
```

Am i doing this right?

I basically need to nest the raw sql in a transaction if one is already ongoing,
else just execute it right away if there is no transaction `begin` called.

This works as expected if i do `db.set_autocommit(False)` then `execute_sql` then `commit()`.
It also works inside the `atomic()` context manager.

---

To give some context, I am working on a web application, on logistics,
and our codebase uses Flask and an SQLAlchemy `scoped_session` with `autocommit` set to True.
It does not use the SQLAlchemy ORM (due to.. historical reasons)
and instead just uses the `Session` object and its
`execute()`, `begin()`, `begin_nested()`, `rollback()` and `remove()` methods.

The way it does it is by defining a Session `Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=True))` in a file,
and then calling `session = Session()` everywhere in the codebase, and executing the queries using `session.execute("SQL")`
Sometimes, a `session.begin()` is called, so the query does not execute until the commit (or rollback).

**We'd now really like to use peewee.**
But.. the codebase is built on this session. So this has to be spoofed.
Going and changing every file is impossible, and not enough test cases to boot (for.. historical reasons).

---

Also I had some questions but I don't know where to ask them, so I hope you don't mind if I put them here:

- Is this db object (and its connection) bound to the thread it is executing in?
  Basically will there be some bug if db is imported from two different files, and `db.begin()` is called from each?
  I can see in the ipython shell that the `id` for the `db` object above is the same per thread,
  so am I correct in assuming that unless the psycopg2 connection is recreated, this should be isolated?
- To spoof the sqlalchemy `Session`, I have created a wrapper class that returns the kind of session required,
  the SQLA `Session` object, or the wrapper I've written for peewee to spoof that.

  ```
  class SessionMocker(object):
      # DO NOT make this a singleton. Sessions will break

      def __init__(self, orm_type=ORM_TYPES.SQLA):
          assert orm_type in ORM_TYPES, "Invalid session constructor type"
          super(SessionMocker, self).__init__()
          self.orm_type = orm_type

      def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if self.orm_type == ORM_TYPES.SQLA:
              return SQLASession(*args, **kwargs)

          if self.orm_type == ORM_TYPES.PEEWEE:
              # For now lets assume no slave
              return SessionWrapper(*args, **kwargs)

          raise NotImplementedError

      def __getattr__(self, item):
          """
          Assuming this will never be called without calling Session() first.
          Else there is no way to tell what type of Session class (ORM) is required, since that can't be passed.
          """

          if self.orm_type == ORM_TYPES.SQLA:
              kls = SQLASession
          elif self.orm_type == ORM_TYPES.PEEWEE:
              kls = SessionWrapper
          else:
              raise NotImplementedError

          return getattr(kls, item)

  Session = SessionMocker(ORM_TYPES.SQLA)
  ```

I figured this will allow the codebase to make a transparent and seamless switch over to using peewee without having to change it everywhere.
How can i do this in a better way?

Answer (score 5):

The docs explain how to do this: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/transactions.html#autocommit-mode

But, tl;dr, you need to disable autocommit before begin/commit/rollback will work like you expect:

```
db.set_autocommit(False)
db.begin()
try:
    user.delete_instance(recursive=True)
except:
    db.rollback()
    raise
else:
    try:
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
        raise
finally:
    db.set_autocommit(True)
```

Comment: I've tried that, and in fact i've tried to wrap your `_atomic`, `transaction` and `savepoint` context managers inside a `SessionWrapper` object that calls `atomic` internally, but i guess sqlalchemy's scoped session is more than just commits and rollbacks. In the end we had to drop our plan for peewee, but i hope i can use it in our upcoming microservices in the future. It seems exactly what we need.
If you would like to examine the wrapper I can send it to you?

Comment: If it's of no use to you, I'm not sure what benefit there would be to my looking at it. Good luck with SQLAlchemy, tho

Comment: Well thanks anyways, and a thanks for the awesome library that is peewee. I really wanted a simpler ORM for lightweight projects, and this helps. Also are you completely dropping support for django like filters (`some__join`)?

Comment: @coleifer , link is broken

Comment: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/3.6.0/peewee/database.html?highlight=autocommit#autocommit-mode works.

Answer (score -1):

The default value for autocommit is True but the default value of autorollback is False. Setting autorollback as True automatically rollback when an exception occurs while executing a query. Can't be sure but maybe this mess the situation. So, if you want try it with the autorollback as False